# Abbreviating “se connecter / s'inscrire”

Tags: informatique, abréviations

I am making a website. The website has to be translated into French.
For the button which says "Login / Signup" I have come up with the 
translation "Se Connecter / S'Inscrire".

This however is a bit too long and messes up the layout. Is there a
shorter abbreviation I can use which will still be understood just as
clearly?

Comment: Welcome to the world of multilingual websites. French being most of. The time longer than English, it's common usage to do the HTML/CSS with French content in rather than English...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

French is often not as compact as English (really, 5 more chars is too much ?)

- Connexion is slightly shorter
- Maybe 'Entrer' (Enter) would reasonably mean the same to you ?
- Or if the ID box is right after, simply 'Nom:' (Name:)

Comment: It's 12 chars more! Connexion is better for Login, but how about Sign Up? Would "Signer" work?

Comment: oh, here login and signup are not 2 synonym ? it's look so for me, so maybe you could translate  "login / signup" by "connexion" and that's it !

Comment: No, login implies you have already signed up :P

Comment: *Inscription* would make sense but it's longer…

Comment: "Entrer / S'inscrire" ? BTW what is your exact constraint ?

Comment: Looking for about 18-19 chars altogether so "Entrer / S'inscrire" works but is that what you usually see on french websites for logging in or signing up?

Comment: Well, you decided this length constraint ! Amazon is an endless "indentifiez-vous" / "Nouveau client ? Commencer ici" ;-)  A lot use "Se Connecter / S'Inscrire".
Entrer will be understood for "se connecter"

Comment: Sweet, I'll use that then! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll have to design larger buttons... but the more I think about it, 'signer', though uncommon, would be readily understood especially when opposed to 's'inscrire'. At least for me if I chanced upon it.